# C++ Error C2447? What am I missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I don't know if I'm going crazy, or just that everything I've read on this error doesn't apply to my situation. But I'm getting these errors when I compile my project:

```
1>f:\program files\testengine\testengine\testengine\game.cpp(10) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '{ctor}'
1>f:\program files\testengine\testengine\testengine\game.cpp(11) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>f:\program files\testengine\testengine\testengine\game.cpp(11) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>f:\program files\testengine\testengine\testengine\game.cpp(15) : error C2059: syntax error : 'public'
1>f:\program files\testengine\testengine\testengine\game.cpp(16) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>f:\program files\testengine\testengine\testengine\game.cpp(16) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

So, I Google'd the error, and everyone said this is caused by things like extra and/or missing semicolons and brackets. But I've looked over my code a lot (there's not very much!) and I don't see any of that, unless of course, as I previously suggested, I'm going crazy...

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef _SBE_CGAME_
#define _SBE_CGAME_

class CGame
{
public:
    CGame();
    ~CGame();

    void DoLoop();
};
#endif //_SBE_CGAME_
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"

extern CGame* m_gGame;

CGame::CGame()
{
    //
}

~CGame::CGame()
{
    //
}

public void CGame::DoLoop()
{
    SwapBuffers(hDC);
}
```

**Base.h**

```
#include <windows.h>        // Header File For Windows ==NEEDS TO COME BEFORE GL.H AND GLU.H==
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h> 

#include "Properties.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Renderer.h"

#ifndef _SBE_BASE_
#define _SBE_BASE_

extern CGame* m_gGame;

#endif //_SBE_BASE_
```

**Globals.cpp**

```
#include "base.h"

//=================================================================================
// Here is where we define all the global variables
//=================================================================================
CGame* m_gGame = new CGame();
```

What am I overlooking? I will admit, its been a while since I've programmed C++, but I reread class definition articles and all sorts of things. I have this not-so-strange feeling that its going to be something very silly, that I should have seen.

Comment: `CGame::~CGame()` instead of `~CGame::CGame()`. Granted the compiler could have been a little more forthcoming, but well...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I think you should make that an answer.

Comment: You need to remove the public in your Game.cpp, it cannot be out of line and it cannot address a specific functions (it has to come with : after and it addresses all functions after it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write `CGame::~CGame()` instead of `~CGame::CGame()` for the destructor. It's always the class name first (`CGame`) and only then the member name (`~CGame`).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I ignored the destructor completely, because I got the problem originally from the public keyword, thanks though :)

Answer (score 9):

In Game.cpp:

```
~CGame::CGame()
```

should be

```
CGame::~CGame()
```

And drop the `public` keyword on the definition of `CGame::DoLoop`.

Comment: +1 I didn't check the rest, thinking they were all cascades from the destructor.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, too. I had two problems :(

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <windows.h>        // Header File For Windows ==NEEDS TO COME BEFORE GL.H AND GLU.H==
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h> 

#include "Properties.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Renderer.h"

#ifndef _SBE_BASE_
#define _SBE_BASE_

extern CGame* m_gGame;

#endif //_SBE_BASE_
```

Why are you only include-guarding part of this file?

```
#ifndef _SBE_BASE_
#define _SBE_BASE_
#include <windows.h>        // Header File For Windows ==NEEDS TO COME BEFORE GL.H AND GLU.H==
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h> 

#include "Properties.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Renderer.h"

extern CGame* m_gGame;

#endif //_SBE_BASE_
```

Anyway, my guess is something weird in Properties.h or Renderer.h

Comment: Oh? Should I be doing it to the includes, too? We learn something new everyday!

Comment: @smoth190 - In general I think it should be fine (since the includes will have include guards), but I think it's generally good practice since it reduces the amount of work the compiler has to do and protects you against badly written headers.

Answer (score 2):

you have mis-declared your destructor

it should be

```
CGame::~CGame()
```